# How do you close an application when some WaitHandle is in the middle of a call to WaitOne?

Tags: c#, multithreading, idisposable, shutdown, waithandle

Is there a standard way to close out an application "cleanly" while some `WaitHandle` objects may be in the state of a current blocking call to `WaitOne`?

For example, there may be a background thread that is spinning along in a method like this:

```
while (_request.WaitOne())
{
    try
    {
        _workItem.Invoke();
    }
    finally
    {
        OnWorkCompleted();
    }
}
```

I see no obvious way to dispose of this thread without calling `Thread.Abort` (which from what I understand is discouraged). Calling `Close` on the `_request` object (an `AutoResetEvent`), however, will throw an exception.

Currently, the thread that is running this loop has its `IsBackground` property set to `true`, and so the application *appears* to close properly. However, since `WaitHandle` implements `IDisposable`, I'm unsure if this is considered kosher or if that object really ought to be disposed before the app exits.

Is this a bad design? If not, how is this scenario typically dealt with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define an additional `WaitHandle` called `_terminate` that will signal a request to terminate the loop and then use `WaitHandle.WaitAny` instead of `WaitHandle.WaitOne`.

```
var handles = { _request, _terminate };
while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles) == 0)
{
  try
  {
    _workItem.Invoke();
  }
  finally
  {
    OnCompleteWork();
  }
}
```

Comment: Totally makes sense. But does this mean that it's *not* OK to simply have the thread running this loop initialized with `IsBackground = true` (so that when the app exits, the loop terminates even though the `WaitHandle` is still waiting)?

Comment: @Dan: That's probably okay too, but this method would allow you to gracefully end the thread without having to shutdown the entire application.

Comment: Hi.I just asked you in another question about this pattern, Is this the pattern for stopping a thread via wait handle ? ( instead of using abort/interrupt) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: More or less...yes. Normally only a single `ManualResetEvent` would be created and then `WaitOne` would be called with a timeout parameter to simulate a polling interval in an infinite loop. If `WaitOne` returns `false` then then loop keeps spinning. If it returns `true` (because `Set` was called to request a shutdown) then the loop stops.

Comment: Brian Thanks  , If I may , 1 more question : why do you say `ManualResetEvent` ? if a single thread is waiting - an `AutoResetEvent` should be fine and more appropriate to this call (because i have just one thread waiting and  i dont want all waiting threads to be signaled). am I right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yep, an `AutoResetEvent` will usually work fine as well. I just always use an MRE for this because a shutdown request is typically always in the "requested" state. If you happen to call `WaitOne` repeatedly you may want it to keep returning `true`. An ARE does not retain the signaled state. It goes away after `WaitOne` returns.

Comment: Brian , According to your answer in this post , When I want to have an option of Stopping a thread ( I want to kill him gracefully) , there are 2 options : 1 to use your answer which says : _as long as you don't signal me , im still runninng_ **or** _I can use a volatile field ( also in infinite loop) and check its flag whether to stop or continue._  What do you suggest ? ( if it's too much - I can ask it as a separate question - thanks.).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No need to post another question...I would start with a `volatile` field. If that does not satisfy your needs then try an MRE or ARE.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `IsBackground` property to `true`... it should automatically close the thread when your app ends.

Alternately, you can interrupt the thread by calling [`Thread.Interrupt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx) and handle the [`ThreadInterruptedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadinterruptedexception.aspx). Another idea is to call `_request.Set()` and make the while loop check a volatile flag to determine if the application is closing or if it should continue:

```
private volatile bool _running = true;
while(_request.WaitOne() && _running)
{
    //...
}

// somewhere else in the app
_running = false;
_request.Set();
```

Comment: So you're saying there's no need to call `Close` on the `WaitHandle` as long as the thread is a background thread?

Comment: @Dan, it has always exited correctly for me... I'm looking for something in the documentation to back that claim up.

Comment: This is the exact same thing as Thread.Abort().  It is just that the CLR will call it.

Answer (score 1):

When a thread is blocking (regardless of what it's blocking on) you can call `Thread.Interrupt()` This will cause the exception `ThreadInterruptedException` (I believe, it might be a little different) You can handle this exception on the thread itself and do any neccesary clean up.

It's worth noting, that the thread will only throw the `ThreadInterruptedException` when it is blocking, if it's not blocking it won't be thrown until it next tries to block.

This is the "safe" way of ending threads from what I've read on the subject.

also worth noting: If the object implements both IDisposable and a finializer (which it will if it uses unmanaged resources) the GC will call the finalizer which normally calls dispose. Normally this is non-deterministic. However you can pretty much guarantee they will get called on application exit. Only under very special circumstances they wouldn't. (A .net environment termininating exception such as `StackOverflowException` is thrown)

Answer (score 0):

I think the operating system will clean up after your process has finished. Because your thread is marked as IsBackground the CLR will end the process and all the threads within, so this is not a problem.